# App Crash When I use CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepngrepresentation, cgimagesource

I just use `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` to scale down `UIImage` size .  I get crash Message :

> "IIONumber -- 'num' is not a CFNumberRef" .

I could not find what is it? 
Thanks

```
func scaleDownImage()->void{   

   var nextImage = UIImage()
    if let img = nextDicData["img"] as? UIImage{
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
        if let cgimageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data! as CFData, nil){
            let option : [NSString : Any] = [kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : self.outputSize, kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : true]
            // That's crash at bellow line      
            if let scaleImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(cgimageSource, 0, option as CFDictionary){
                nextImage = UIImage(cgImage: scaleImage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary option passed to CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex method contains kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize. It should be CFNumber.

**Apple's documentation on kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize**

> The maximum width and height in pixels of a thumbnail. If this key is
>   not specified, the width and height of a thumbnail is not limited and
>   thumbnails may be as big as the image itself. If present, this key
>   must be a CFNumber value.

Please ensure it is CFNumber. I believe thats the reason for the crash. Please find the Apple's reference here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/kcgimagesourcethumbnailmaxpixelsize?language=objc

Try options like this.

```
let options = [
    kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
    kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
    kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 250 /* some size */] as CFDictionary
```

Comment: thanks Anand, image still keep the same ratio? , I have loaded a lot of images and my app crash memory issues. Any suggestion for me?

Comment: @Anna, Try adding "kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true" in options. I have edited my answer above. see if it helps.